# asp.net listbox vs winforms listbox

Tags: asp.net, listbox

The following code is for winforms:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.DataSource = Fruit.Get();
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        }

        private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object li = listBox1.SelectedItem;

            Fruit fr = (Fruit) li;

            label1.Text = fr.Name;
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to use the same technique in asp.net?

If no, then what is the alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible in ASP.NET.

As an alternative, you can store your fruit items in Dictionary<string, Fruit>  collection and you can get your selected Fruit like that :

```
// Assume that your datasource is Dictionary<string, Fruit> myFruits
Fruit fr = myFruits[listBox1.SelectedValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it *exactly* like that, as I'm quite rusty in winforms, but here's how i'd try it in asp.net

1.)  Bind your listbox in Page_PreRender()

`listBox1.DataSource = Fruit.Get();

listBox1.DataTextField = "Name";

listBox1.DataValueField = "ID";

listBox1.DataBind();`

2.)  I'm not sure what the equivalent "OnClick" event would be, but you could hook into the SelectedIndexChanged event like so (triggered by another button):

`var li = listBox1.SelectedItem;

label1.Text = li.Text;`

Comment: Well, I did this already. I was just searching for a better technique. I.e. to work with objects.

Comment: Meanwhile, Canavar's technique is very good. It solves a lot of problems.